# What is the form of axios returned data through DevTools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-devtools

I am learning about Hooks, React Context, and other things, but I feel that I don't understand how DevTools work. My axios call returns some data which updates the state. I can see the state change and my console.log displays the information.

This is state under Hooks:

[image]

This is what the `console.log(todos)` spits out:
[image]

This is how console log looks expanded:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know if the todos have the form of `{[{_id, title, userId}]}` or `[{_id, title, userId}]` under DevTools.

I think it is the latter and tried to access via `console.log(todos[0])`,  `console.log(todos[0]['title'])`, etc but those return `undefined` yet `console.log(todos)` doesn't. Is there a reason why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

If `console.log(todos)` logs this object `{todos:[...]}` it means that the **todos object** contains a **todos property** that contains the array. That is probably confusing you since you need to select `todos` once again:

`console.log(todos.todos)`
(The full selector will then be `console.log(todos.todos[0]['title'])` )

My guess is that you saved the complete Redux state into a todos variable in your code via `var todos = state;`.

I suggest you save the state in another variable name instead to avoid the confusion:

`var reduxState = state;`

...or save only the todos state:

`var reduxTodosState = state.todos;`

Comment: I was playing with the code earlier and noticed that when I used typeof; it threw back an object. You are correct, I returned the response.data as todos and confused myself later on as I work on and off on this code. I tried todos.todos[0]['title'] but the page says **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**.